# How to add multiple columns in cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, cql, datastax-java-driver

I need to add some `new columns` to my `existing column_family/table` in cassandra.
I can add single column like this :

```
ALTER TABLE keyspace_name.table_name ADD column_name cql_type;
```

Can I add all new columns using a single query? If yes, how to do it using `cql` and `datastax cassandra driver`?

Comment: I think it is not possible. See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cassandra/cassandra_alter_table.htm and https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html.

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10411

Comment: Remember to be careful with schema agreement when modifying schema programmatically

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is fixed in Cassandra 3.6
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10411

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD (colname1 int, colname2 int)
```